# visual studio DataSet designer with stored-procedures ? what is this icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedures, schema, dataset-designer

What does this icon mean is Visual studio, visual Data Set designer.
I have several stored procedures.

can you help me understand,

- why the one on top of the list has a
  small "check mark"
- why I can't delete it if I need to.
- This is not the case with the rest.
  Why is this "special" ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what it means, but it is a Check Mark, not a tick.

Comment: Thanks, have made the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that item contains the method(s) that define the schema of the table the TableAdapter is part of.

The default names are Fill and GetData.  Looks like you renamed them.

Comment: I renamed them as I was trying to reconfigure them and wasn't successful. So decided to change the name,  Add new one with default name and delete the previous none. This is not working either.

Comment: Dealing with tables in typed DataSets can be unpleasant.  I would delete the table and recreate it.  Be sure to back up the other TableAdapter methods first though.

Comment: Any idea, how can be backup them. It is a nightmare redoing all that ?

Comment: If re-writing the queries is a problem, you can copy them out of the xsd file if you open it with a text editor, e.g. Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Each table has a default query (The one on top with the check on it). When you dragged your tables in to the dataset to create the query, it wrote a SQL statement which it uses to schema your table. Keep that query simple, you might not actually use it in code, and you can always edit that query to update the table schema.  In the picture you provided, your default query is actually a stored procedure.

Every time you open the default query it connects to your datasource and allows you to select new columns that weren't in there before. If you want to update your existing columns, delete all the columns out of the table before you attempt to open the query. When you save the query, your updated columns get added back.

Make sure your connection string has permissions to view column information.